# React Submit Form Not Sending POST Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a frontend for a Spring Boot application and I chose React but I do not have much experience with React or JavaScript.
So I have a form that I am trying to use to send a post request but when I press the submit button, nothing seems to happen. I assume its my onSubmit handler that's the problem but I don't know what is wrong with it. When I send the POST request manually it works fine so I don't think it's the REST API thats causing an issue.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Create extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      title: '',
      description: ''
    };
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, email, title, description } = this.state;

   axios.post('/create', { name, email, title, description })
      .then((result) => {
        this.props.history.push("/")
      });


  }

  render() {
    const { name, email, title, description } = this.state;
    return (
      <div class="container">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
              Send Message
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h4><Link to="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> Message List</Link></h4>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
             <div class="form-group">
               <label for="name">Name:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" onChange={this.onChange}/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
               <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" onChange={this.onChange}/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" onChange={this.onChange}/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" onChange={this.onChange}/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    );
      }
    }

export default Create;
```

Comment: If you log the error, what do you get?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I was expecting it to POST the data I enter into the form and then return to localhost:8080/

Comment: add a `console.log('test')` on `onSubmit()` function and see if it is been called on button action.

Comment: The function onSubmit() is actually beeing invoked? Could be a `bind()` issue...

Comment: I am running this as a frontend to a Spring Boot application so when I run it through Maven I am not getting any output in the console even with console.log in the onSubmit function. My guess is that it is not getting invoked at all

Comment: You're posting to `/create`, which probably isn't what you want. Use the full API url and see if it works.

Comment: I made a fork here: http://jsfiddle.net/h3spgwya/ Despite other errors (and bad practises), the method invokes properly.

Comment: I tried changing the API url but it doesn't make a difference. The code doesn't seem to reach the post function since even if I put in a URL that I know doesn't work there is no error

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of React is, You do not update state property directly (or React wouldn't know that the state has changed).

It's not easy to tell how React would behave if you do so.
So instead of setting the state value directly,

```
onChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
}
```

Change it like this and try to submit again.

```
onChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
```